Transact SQL, GROUP BY using Case with aggregate function
I am trying to enable using a variable/parameter along with a 'CASE' expression to determine the "Group By" clause to be used.
I am getting the following error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
Column 'Field_1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The sample SQL I am using is the following:
DECLARE @OrderBy nvarchar(15) = 'Date';
DECLARE @StartDate date = '01/01/2023';
DECLARE @EndDate date = '12/31/2023';

SELECT Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, SUM(Field_4) AS 'Sum'
FROM Table_1
WHERE
    Field_2 IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
    AND Field_3 > 1
    AND Field_3 < 20
    AND Field_1 >= @StartDate
    AND Field_1 <= @EndDate

/*
    If @OrderBy = 'Date' 
        THEN "GROUP BY" should be
            GROUP BY Field_1, Field_2, Field_3
    IF @OrderBy = 'Location'
        THEN "GROUP BY" should be
            GROUP BY Field_3, Field_2, Field_1
*/
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Date' 
        THEN [Field_1]
    END, 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Date' 
        THEN [Field_2]
    END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Date' 
        THEN [Field_3]
    END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Location' 
        THEN [Field_2]
    END, 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Location' 
        THEN [Field_3]
    END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Location' 
        THEN [Field_1]
    END

The idea is that the returned results could be grouped by "Field_1", "Field_2", "Field_3" OR "Field_3", "Field_2", "Field_1" depending on the input parameter @OrderBy.
The goal is got be able to use an input parameter in order to determine the correct "Group By" so that I can have a single stored procedure to handle any case rather than having to have multiple stored procedures.
Anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Well if it's grouped by Field_1 how do you want to aggregate the other fields? It's not clear what result you want.

A [mre] with sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer

An order of columns in GROUP BY doesn't matter. Your only want conditional order of columns in ORDER BY
SELECT Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, SUM(Field_4) AS 'Sum'
FROM Table_1
WHERE
    Field_2 IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
    AND 
    Field_3 > 1
    AND
    Field_3 < 20
    AND
    Field_1 >= @StartDate
    AND
    Field_1 <= @EndDate
GROUP BY
    [Field_1],[Field_2], [Field_3]
ORDER BY
    CASE @OrderBy 
      WHEN 'Date' THEN [Field_1] 
      WHEN 'Location' THEN [Field_2]
    END,
    CASE @OrderBy 
      WHEN 'Date' THEN [Field_2] 
      WHEN 'Location' THEN [Field_3]
    END,
    CASE @OrderBy 
      WHEN 'Date' THEN [Field_2] 
      WHEN 'Location' THEN [Field_1]
    END


the group by is also differently sorted and that would change the resultset

The "Order By" shouldn't have been included in the sample, my bad, I have removed it).  The problem is with the "Group By".  I have a need to group by either "Field_1" or "Field_3" depending on the input of a parameter.  The problem is that I get the "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 77" error when trying to use the CASE statement of the "GROUP BY" clause.

Thanks!  I tried it and it worked as you said.  I now need to go read more about "ORDER BY" and "GROUP BY".

@EricB Be sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem.   ACCEPTING serves a little "Thank You" for Serg's time and talent and indicates to other contributors the issue is closed
